# Cordova windows phone FileTransfer.download "Access is denied" error

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, file-transfer

I'm developing a mobile app which should download an image from internet and save it on the device for offline use. 
I'm using `apache cordova on visual studio 2015` and `FileTransfer` plugin and it works on android without any problem. 
but when I test it on windows phone, it throws an exception 
 `"0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied."`

this is a sample of what I'm doing :

```js
var uri = encodeURI(downloadPath);
    window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fs.root.getDirectory('cordova', { create: true });
        var filePath = fs.root.fullPath + '/cordova/' + downloadPath.split('/').pop();

            fileTransfer.download(
                uri,
                fileURL,
                function (entry) {

                    $("#dli").attr("src", entry.toURL());

                },
                function (error) {
                    alert("download error source " + error.source);
                    alert("download error target " + error.target);
                    alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                },
                false,
                {

                }
            );
        });
```

I also tried wrapping the code into `"MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction"` function but no luck ...